# Custom events in Expression Blend

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am developing my own FTP client and I want to create a nice GUI using expression blend. I was wondering how to create a custom event so that I can trigger an animation when an upload completes. In other words, is there a way I can subscribe to an even in expression blend/ create my own event? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a new `public` property called `bool DownloadCompleted { get; set; }` in your ViewModel, and then use a `ControlStoryboardAction` with a `DataTrigger` to watch for a change in the `DownloadCompleted` property to `true` ... the animation will then be started.

There's a good explanation how to do it here.

- http://www.basarat.com/2011/05/expression-blend-starting-storyboard.html
- http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/10/12/animating-with-storyboards-in-blend/

There's no need to create your own Event to notify of the completed download, however, you can do that if you wish...just choose an `EventTrigger` instead...and point the `SourceName` to the named element that's in your XAML that either has the event raised on it or (if it's a bubbling event, then you have the flexibility of watching the event on other elements....as long as the event bubbles through them).